# I can't figure out how to calculate the maximum and minimum signed number without using climits in C++

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed

I'm currently working on an assignment for my CS course. I'm trying to print the maximum and minimum signed number for the datatypes int, short and long.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I've been using the sizeof() function to determine how many bytes each data type carries, then used pow() from the cmath library.

This is the math/code I've used for calculating the maximum amount of the signed short:
(int)pow(2, sizeof(short)*8)-1;

This outputs the maximum unsigned number, rather than the maximum signed number. I could divide that by 2 but not entirely sure how to calculate the negative part other than printing with a "-" in front..

More detailed code of what I have right now:

```
 42     int shortmax_calculate;
 43     shortmax_calculate = (pow(2, sizeof(short)*8)-1)/2;
 44
 45     float shortmin_calculate;
 46     shortmin_calculate = (int)pow(2, sizeof(short)*8)/2;
 47
 48     short unsigned shortunsigned_calculate;
 49     shortunsigned_calculate = pow(2, sizeof(short)*8)-1;
 50
 51     int intmax_calculate;
 52     intmax_calculate = (int)pow(2, sizeof(int)*8)-1;
 53
 54
 55     cout << "Maxmimum short (signed): "<< shortmax_calculate << endl;
 56     cout << "Minimum short (signed): " << "-" << shortmin_calculate << endl;
 57     cout << "Maximum short (unsigned): " << shortunsigned_calculate << endl;
 58     cout << "Maximum int (signed): " << intmax_calculate << endl;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Assuming two's complement you might want to look at [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number)

Comment: Are you allowed to use limits.h ? For signed char, the min is -128 and max is 127.  Try printing them in hex.

Comment: Look up two's complement (the format generally used to represent signed number in binary) and bitwise operations (great for manipulating numbers at the binary level) e.g. shifts.

Comment: I assume `<limits>` is also off the table?, as `std::numeric_limits<short>::max()` and the corresponding `min` would easily give what you seek, and be one heluvalot more efficient than invoking `pow`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use C++11, use the [**limits**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) standard header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
...

{
    std::cout << "Maxmimum short (signed): " <<
        std::numeric_limits<short>::max() << std::endl;

    // repeat replacing with 'unsigned short', 'int', 'unsigned int'
    // in template class function: std::numeric_limits<type>, using
    // max() or min() as required.
}
```

Have a look at [clang's](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/limits) implementation - search for `__libcpp_numeric_limits` to see how it does the evaluation. It might give you some ideas for a template if you can't use C++11.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you are looking for is just to add one to the max you calculate. I modified your code a bit below (its in C sorry).

```
  short shortmax_calculate;
  shortmax_calculate = (pow(2, sizeof(short)*8)-1)/2;

  short shortmin_calculate;
  shortmin_calculate = shortmax_calculate + 1;

  short unsigned shortunsigned_calculate;
  shortunsigned_calculate = pow(2, sizeof(short)*8)-1;

  int intmax_calculate;
  intmax_calculate = (int)pow(2, sizeof(int)*8)-1;
  int intmin_calculate = intmax_calculate + 1;

  printf("Maximum short (signed): %i\n",shortmax_calculate);
  printf("Minimum short (signed): %i\n",shortmin_calculate);
  printf("Maximum short (unsigned): %i\n", shortunsigned_calculate);
  printf("Maximum int (signed): %i\n", intmax_calculate);
  printf("Minimum int (signed): %i\n", intmin_calculate);
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
Maximum short (signed): 32767 
Minimum short (signed): -32768
Maximum short (unsigned): 65535 
Maximum int (signed): 2147483647 
Minimum int (signed): -2147483648
```

This is because of how the computer stores negative numbers. For instance: max short (signed) is 01111111 which is 127. Min signed is stored as 10000000 (−128). See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In two's complement, -1 will have all bits set. If you convert it to unsigned and shift it right by 1, it will be the largest possible signed number since the sign bit will be replaced by a zero. If you take the bitwise inverse of that, it will be the smallest possible negative number.

```
short shortmax_calculate = static_cast<short>(static_cast<unsigned short>(-1) >> 1);
short shortmin_calculate = ~shortmax_calculate;
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit of template code does the job.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <size_t S> struct Max
{
   static intmax_t get()
   {
      return ((Max<S-1>::get() << 8) + 0xFF);
   }
};

template <> struct Max<1>
{
   static intmax_t get()
   {
      return 0x7F;
   }
};

template <size_t S> struct Min
{
   static intmax_t get()
   {
      return ((Min<S-1>::get() << 8));
   }
};

template <> struct Min<1>
{
   static intmax_t get()
   {
      return -0x80;
   }
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Max for int: " << Max<sizeof(int)>::get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Min for int: " << Min<sizeof(int)>::get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Max for short: " << Max<sizeof(short)>::get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Min for short: " << Min<sizeof(short)>::get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Max for signed char: " << Max<sizeof(signed char)>::get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Min for signed char: " << Min<sizeof(signed char)>::get() << std::endl;
}
```

This is what I get on my machine:

```
Max for int: 2147483647
Min for int: -2147483648
Max for short: 32767
Min for short: -32768
Max for signed char: 127
Min for signed char: -128
```